# Can we call the [scansion] tag [metre]/[meter] instead?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

We have a tag [scansion](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scansion), with a synonym [meter](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meter):

> For questions about determining and representing the meter of a poem, a practice called scansion.

**Can we change the master tag name to [meter](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meter), and have [scansion](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scansion) as a synonym instead?** I'm pretty sure the word "[meter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metre_(poetry))" (in the context of poetry) is more likely to be familiar to most people than "[scansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scansion)". It's worth noting that most of the questions with the [scansion](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scansion) tag have either been asked by, or had the tag edited in by, high-rep users.

Comment: I think I already asked a mod about this in chat some time ago, but got no response. So here I am on meta.

Comment: Wow, that was a fast 7 upvotes, especially over the Xmas period. Seems there's more active meta users than I'd thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes!** Metre (or "meter" if we must use American English) refers to the rhythmic structure of verse, whereas scansion refers to determining the metre. However, not all questions about metre are about how to determine the metre.

Unless we really need to distinguish between questions about scansion on the one hand and other questions about metre on the other, I think we should make the tag `scansion` a synonym of `metre` or `meter`.

Answer (score 2):

Done; there seems to be a pretty strong sentiment in favor of switching them around, so... I switched them.

[scansion](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scansion) will now remap to [meter](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meter). (Tags are supposed to be in American English, but I took the liberty of adding [metre](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metre) as a synonym of [meter](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meter), for all you Brits out there.)

---

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Comment: Just adding the [meta-tag:status-completed] tag already gives us this information :-P